# Memset function in C initialised all the arrays

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, initialization, memset

I was trying to initialise a array made by pointer:

the code I used was:

```
    int c = 15;
    Struct *Pointer[c] = {NULL};
    memset( pointer, 0, c *sizeof(pointer) );
```

It worked, But this memset() function not only initialised my Pointer array, but also initialise all my other arrays...

is there any way to fix it?

I can not use for(){} or while function as it will increase my Time complixcity...

Cheers'

Comment: A more interesting adventure is what compiler you're using that allows an initial value assignment to a VLA. None of mine do (clang and msvc), so if `Struct *Pointer[c] = {NULL};` "works" I'm curious as to how. I assume the `Pointer` vs `pointer` different is just a typo (that I also don't understand, as there is literally no "typing" to introduce a "typo" when copy/pasting what is supposed to be functioning code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(pointer)` is the size of the entire array `pointer`. Multiplying integers larger than 1 to that for size to `memset()` will cause out-of-range access.

Remove the harmful multiplication.

```
int c = 15;
Struct *Pointer[c] /* = {NULL} */; /* VLA cannot be initialized */

/* some other code that uses Pointer */

memset(Pointer, 0, sizeof(Pointer));
```

Comment: Hey Mike - Thank you for your answer - You are right - I miss typed sizeof(pointer) to sizeof(Struct)...ah...I am so dumb!!!!!!! 
I found that I can not use 
Struct *Pointer[c] = {NULL}
as the C is a variable - the compiler won't let me do it.

Comment: @0___________ Sorry Mate it was my bad - I should't have {NULL}, in C it doesn't work that way

Comment: @0___________ [This can be valid](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MJfhvYruBWi2Raij).

Answer (score 1):

```
memset(Pointer, 0, sizeof(Pointer));
```

or

```
memset(Pointer, 0, c * sizeof(*Pointer));
```

Spot the difference.

You can answer your question yourself if you put some research effort and printed out the `sizeof(Pointer)` and calculate why `c * sizeof(Pointer)` is wrong.